# How to replace with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const data = 'I///m John'
console.log(data.(/\//gm.replace("'"))
```

I want I'm John. I have also to check /// is available or not. If available then change /// to ' ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `+` [quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers) for `one or more than one search`.

**[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method is available on `String.prototype`

```js
const data = "I///m John";

const result = data.replace(/\/+/g, "'");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are using the .replace() in the wrong location.
Try it like this.

```js
let message = "Hello there";
message = message.replace(/(Hello)/g, "Hey");
console.log(message) // "Hey there"
```